# For a semisimple ring, if $M \oplus P \cong N \oplus P$, then $M \cong N$ (finitely generated $M$, $N$, $P$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> ***Problem***
>
> Let $R$ be a semisimple ring (i.e. $R$ is semisimple as a left $R$-module). Show that if $M,N$ and $P$ are finitely generated $R$-modules such that $M \oplus P \cong N \oplus P$, then $M \cong N$.

I couldn't do much. If $R$ is semisimple, then I can use the following property:

> A ring $R$ is semisimple (again, meaning that ${}_R R$ semisimple) if and only if every $R$-module is semisimple.

With this property, we have that $M$, $N$ and $P$ are semisimple so

\begin{alignat*}{2}
M &= M_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus M_m
&\quad
&\text{with $M_j$ simple submodules of $M$,} \\
N &= N_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus N_n
&\quad
&\text{with $N_j$ simple submodules of $N$, and} \\
P &= P_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus P_r
&\quad
&\text{with $P_j$ simple submodules of $P$.}
\end{alignat*}
So we get
$$
M_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus M_m \oplus P_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus P_r
\cong
N_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus N_n\oplus P_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus P_r \,.
$$

I must use that all of these modules are finitely generated. I would really appreciate suggestions on how could I continue from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing fine so far! The next thing you have to do is to count how often a fixed isomorphism type of irreducible representations occurs on both sides. For this, use the following: If $M=M_1\oplus ...\oplus M_n$ a decomposition of a semi-simple, finitely-generated $R$-module $M$ as a sum of irreducible $R$-modules, and if $I$ is any irreducible $R$-module, then the number of summands $M_i$ that are isomorphic to $I$ is given by the dimension of $\text{Hom}_R(I,M)$ over the division ring $\text{Hom}_R(I,I)$.

Comment: I thought I have understood your solution but then I've realized I couldn't follow you. If you want to, you can see my comment below rschwieb's answer so as to help me to finish from there.

Comment: @user156441 Sure - but where exactly are you having trouble to follow? Given your decompositions of left and right hand side, choose an arbitrary irreducible $R$-module and apply $\text{Hom}_R(I,-)$ to both sides. This will give two isomorphic vector spaces over the division ring $\text{End}_R(I,I)$, and their respective dimensions tell you how many of the $(M_i)_i,(P_j)$ and $(N_i),(up\{P_j)$ are isomorphic to $I$. Cancelling the contribution of the $P_j$ shows that among the $M_i$ there are precisely as many modules isomorphic to $I$ as among the $N_i$. Does this help?

Comment: @user156441 Note that this is different from what rschwieb suggested in that we argue directly and do not employ Krull-Schmidt's Theorem here.

Comment: Sorry again for being so slow, but I am still trying to get it. So, I have $\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M_1) \oplus ... \oplus \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,P_r)=\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,N_1) \oplus ... \oplus \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,P_r)$. Is $\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M)$ the vector space you are considering over $End_R(I,I)$ ($M=M_1 \oplus ... \oplus P_r$)? How can I cancel the contribution of the $P_j$? I see why if among the $M_i$ there are precisely as many isomorphic modules to $I$ as among $N_i$, then each $M_i$ is isomorphic to each $N_i$, but I am not getting all the rest of your solution.

Comment: Btw, how do you know the dimension of $\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M)$ is finite?

Comment: No worries! $\text{Hom}_R(I,M\oplus P)$ and $\text{Hom}_R(I,N\oplus P)$ are the spaces to consider. The rank of the former is the number of modules among the $M_i$ and $P_j$ which are isomorphic to $I$ (in particular, it's finite) - that's because there are no nonzero $R$-linear homomorphisms between non-isomorphic irreducible $R$-modules. Similar for $N_i$ and $P_j$. The $P_j$ contribute the same to both numbers, so you conclude as I described above that among the $M_i$ there are as many modules isomorphic to $I$ as among the $N_i$.

Comment: Thanks, I am starting to get it. I understand why between two R simple modules there are only two possible morphisms (they are isomorphic, or the morphism is zero, by Schur's lemma). To be more explicit about my last doubt: say you consider $Hom_R(I,P_i)$ over $End_R(I,I)$ and suppose $I,P_i$ are isomorphic. Is the rank of $Hom_R(I,P_i)$ 1? Couldn't there exist more than one isomorphism between the two so therefore being at least two different elements in $Hom_R(I,P_i)$? Wouldn't then the dimension (or rank) be 2?

Comment: Note that we're judging the size of $\text{Hom}_R(I,P_i)$ in terms of its rank as a module over $\text{End}_R(I)$, not in terms of number of elements or dimension over some other base field, if present (if there was such a base field, then yes, it can happen that the endomorphisms of an irreducible module do not only consist of scalar multiplications). Then, if $P_i\cong I$, you we have $\text{Hom}_R(I,P_i)\cong\text{Hom}_R(I,I)=\text{End}_R(I,I)$ which is the regular right $\text{End}_R(I)$-module, hence of rank $1$.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience, thanks very much!

Comment: Sure, you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

From where you stopped: apply the Krull-Schmidt theorem to pair up the modules on both sides.

Without loss of generality you can arrange for the $P_i$'s to be paired up with their counterparts. As a result, the modules other than the P's will be paired up. This shows that the parts outside of $P$ are pairwise isomorphic, and so their direct sums are isomorphic.

> I must use that all of these modules are finitely generated.

You already did. You needs this to write all three as *finite* direct sums of simple modules. They would be infinitely generated iff they had infinite length.

Comment: I haven't seen Krull-Schmidt theorem in class, does it occur to you another way of proving this without the theorem? Suppose the number of $M_i,P_j,N_k$ submodules are $m_i,p_j,n_k$, then $m_i+p_j=n_k+p_j$, from here we get $m_i=n_k$. And from here could you help me to correctly justify that there is a correspondence between the $M$ and $N$ simple submodules?

Comment: Well, I've said $m_i+p_j=n_k+m_j$ but now that I think of, I am not so sure this equality holds.

Comment: @user156441 It's worth your time to learn the theorem. It's an elementary result in most texts on modules. Then this theorem becomes an easy corollary. Good luck.